# как испраить SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) в yii?

Tags: mysql, yii

Я понимаю что проблема подключением к бд в laravel исправлял путем очищение кешов и роутов. В yii пробовал не получается создал файл .env для подключения к бд не работает не миграций ни чего
.env

```
APP_NAME=register
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:mrakeyidharhaikonsdf
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=register
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то с ролью пользователя и его доступами в mysql? Попробуйте его пересоздать? [Статья](https://selectel.ru/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-set-privileges-in-mysql/) как это сделать